# Multiple CAPL files having message event handers

Tags: capl

I have created a CAN simulated system in CANoe.I have added two capl files having a CAN message handler for ID 1.Now if i recieve CAN message with ID 1 in which sequence the handlers will be called?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CANoe simulates a distributed system where all nodes run in parallel. In a real system, both nodes would receive the message at the same time. CANoe will call the message handlers sequentially to guarantee atomicity, however, the order of such calls is undefined and should not be relied upon. Any dependency on a particular order means your system will experience race conditions when implemented in hardware.